# getOpenFileNames крашится софт

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qfiledialog, getopenfilename

При вызове метода `getOpenFileNames` происходит краш программы.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(265, 161)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 181, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 181, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 265, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testingOPENfile)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать файл с исходниками"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать файл конечный"))

    def testingOPENfile(self):
        print(0)
        res = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выберите ", None, "*.png *.jpg")
        print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА.** 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(265, 161)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 181, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 50, 181, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 265, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        
#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testingOPENfile)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать файл с исходниками"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать файл конечный"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.testingOPENfile)

    def testingOPENfile(self):
#        res = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выберите ", None, "*.png *.jpg")
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
            self, 
            "Выберите ", 
            "", 
            "Files PNG (*.png);; Files JPG (*.jpg)"
        )
        
        print(files)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> объясните, пожалуйста как работает данный синтаксис
>
> `files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()`
>
> Зачем нужна запятая и нижнее подчеркивание

Результат работы статическая функция [**getOpenFileNames()**](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html?highlight=getopenfilenames#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames) - кортеж.

**`_`** - это имя переменной, вы можете назвать ее как угодно вам, она вам не понадобится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете объяснить, пожалуйста как работает данный синтаксис " files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames"  
Зачем нужна запятая и нижнее подчеркивание

Comment: @maksik172 я добавил некоторые пояснения в свой ответ, проверьте.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour